# SQL Server 2008 R2- Query to get total sales and qty sold by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables STOCK and ITEMS,

I am trying to get a report showing how total items purchased (ITEMS table- items.quanto), total sales for items(ITEMS table- I assume (items.quanto*items.it_unlist) with description(STOCK table- stock.desc1) by month (ITEMS table-items.odr_date) with classification (which is a field in the STOCK table- stock.assoc).

The owner wants this info for each month for 2011, 2012, and YTD 2013

so total qty sold for item with total sales of that item by month 2011, 2012, 2013 YTD

This is my query

```
select items.item, items.quanto, SUM(items.QUANTO*items.it_unlist) as [total cost], stock.desc1, items.it_sdate from items
inner join
stock
on
stock.number = items.item
where IT_SDATE  between '2011-01-01 00:00:00.0' and '2011-12-31 00:00:00.0'
group by items.item, items.quanto, stock.desc1, items.it_sdate
order by IT_SDATE
```

I was hoping to get each item totaled sales and qty by month but this is what I figured out on my own…lol

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  item,
  right(convert(varchar(8), it_sdate, 3), 5) theMonth,
  sum(quanto) totalQuantity,
  sum(quanto * it_unlist) totalSales,
  max(stock.desc1) descr,
  max(stock.assoc) assoc
from 
  items inner join stock on 
    items.item = stock.number
where
  it_sdate > '2011-01-01'
group by
  item,
  right(convert(varchar(8), it_sdate, 3), 5)
order by
  item,
  theMonth
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/246d3/18/0

Comment: One more thing, the owner of my company...wants ALMOST same results but without the totalsales and without the months just between 10/1/2012 and 09/30/2013 and they want the last time WE ordered the item on a PO, the issue I see is that to bring in the 'PURCHASE' table the 'PURITEM' table needs to be joined to because the item# is in PURITEM but not in PURCHASE....PURITEM would be joined with items.number = puritem.number and then purchase would be joined with puritem by puritem.ponumber = purchase.ponumber if that is possible?

Comment: Yes, you would just add those tables to the FROM clause:

FROM 
  purchase p inner join puritem pi on p.ponumber = pi.ponumber, 
  puritem pi inner join items i on pi.number = i.number,
  items i inner join stock s on i.number = s.number

Answer (score 0):

if the item column of the items table is primary key, then you can’t display the each and every item number when you are trying to display the total sales and qty.
And also, the IT_DATE column consists of only one date per month in the table, then only the below query is possible, if not we need to write other query.
if not, you can select.

```
select i.quanto, sum(QUANTO * it_unlist) as [total list], 
s.desc1, i.it_sdate from items i inner join stock s on (s.number = i.item)
where IT_SDATE > 2011-01-01
group by i.it_sdate order by IT_SDATE;
```